# Envio de emails lento com Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, envio-de-email

Estou fazendo alguns testes de envio de emails em massa mas estou achando um tanto quanto lento o processo sendo feito com `Laravel`. O motivo de estar achando o envio lento é que trabalhei em uma empresa onde em média 50 ~ 60 mil emails eram enviados em torno de 10 à 12 horas.Para testar o procedimento estou utilizando apenas 10 e em um primeiro teste foram necessários 45 segundos para finalizar o processo.

**ESTRUTURA DO PROJETO**

Laravel 5.4.*

Banco de dados PostgreSQL para armazenar o nome e emails dos pseudos assinantes, basicamente utilizo 1 só tabela com 5 campos (ID, NOME, EMAIL, CREATED_AT, UPDATED_AT).

Envio dos emails estão sendo feitos com o sistema de filas do Laravel utilizando o redis. Tomei a iniciativa de utilizar a extensão PHPREDIS ao contrario da padrão que já vem com o Laravel que é a Predis, fiz isso por conta do desempenho ser superior.

**FLUXO**

Link na pagina inicial chamando uma rota

```
<div class="links">
    <a href="{{Route('enviarNews')}}">Enviar News</a>
</div>
```

A rota chama esse controller, que por sua vez chama uma Job como vocês podem ver

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Jobs\MailJob;

class MailController extends Controller{

    public function enviarNews(){
        dispatch(new MailJob());

        return 'Sua newsletter está em processo de preparo e sera enviada em breve.';
    }

}
```

A Job, estou chamando a classe mail.

```
<?php    
namespace App\Jobs;    
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;    
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\MailModel;
use App\Mail\MailSend;   

class MailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.         
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }    
    /**
     * Execute the job.         
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $mails = MailModel::all();            
        foreach ($mails as $mail){
            Mail::to($mail->email)->send(new MailSend($mail));
        }
    }
}
```

Classe MailSend e View

```
<?php    
namespace App\Mail;    
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\MailModel;

class MailSend extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;    
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     * @return void
     */        
    public $mail;        
    public function __construct(MailModel $mail)
    {
        $this->mail = $mail;
    }    
    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from("firemail@testes.com", "Firemail Testes")
        ->subject("Testes de Envio em Massa")
        ->view('mail.news1');
    }
}
```

***View***

```
<p>Ola {{$mail->name}}, estamos testando o envio de emails em massa!</p>
```

Isso é o que esta sendo feito, alguma coisa no meu código pode estar deixando o envio lento? Pelas contas que fiz, com essa métrica atual só poderiam ser enviador cerca de 19200 emails por dia, bem abaixo da que mencionei la em cima e aproveitando, essa lentidão pode ser causada pelo meu servidor SMTP? para esses testes estou utilizando o [SMTP2GO](https://www.smtp2go.com/?partner=vedathak)?

- Pode também ser por conta da minha internet? (Porem em média ela roda a 30mb).
- O que posso fazer para melhorar esse processo e deixar o mais rápido possível?

Comment: Alguém poderia me ajudar a ajeitar a pergunta? Tenho um enorme problema em criar perguntas aqui pois o código sempre fica quebrado.

Comment: Minha dúvida: Esse relato de lentidão ocorreu agora ou sempre foi lento? Você está enviando somente texto ou anexo também?

Comment: Então Everson, eu estou testando essa questão de enviar emails com o Laravel entende? Fiz um pequeno sistema onde eu enviava emails de confirmação para o usuário em algumas requisições e nesse sistema os emails demoravam cerca de 3 segundos para serem enviados. Então respondendo sua pergunta, sempre foi lento desse jeito

Comment: Eu sugiro que você primeiramente faça um teste via telnet (https://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Teste_de_envio_e_recebimento_via_Telnet) com os dados de autenticação, para ter como base se com esse envio diretamente no servidor do smtp demora esses 3 segundos que você relata. Caso demorar provavelmente o problema é no servidor, caso contrário estará no seu código. E  com isso estaremos verificando se há algum problema.

Comment: Ok, estava estudando a parte e li algo na documentação que dizia mais ou menos o seguinte: 

"Os drivers baseados em API, como o Mailgun e o SparkPost, geralmente são mais simples e rápidos do que os servidores SMTP."

Estarei testando também essa outra configuração que eles recomendam e volto a dar respostas sobre o tempo de envio que foi necessario. Obrigado pelo apoio Everson!

Comment: Método SMTP sempre, SEMPRE, SEMPRE será lento. Independente do código utilizado, linguagem ou poder computacional, já que a lentidão encontra-se no servidor SMTP, não na sua infraestrutura. Recomendo utilizar API para essas questões, Mail Queue ou serviços específicos para isso, como por exemplo Sendgrid, Mandrill e etc.